# Frequency of character B in Fibonacci string and time limit exceed error

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion, fibonacci

Consider the character string generated by the following rule:

- F[0] = "A"
- F[1] = "B"
- ...
- F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2] with n > 1

Given two positive integers **n** and **k**. Let's count the number of characters 'B' in the first **k** positions of string **F[n]**.

**I came up with this idea and got time limit exceeded error:**

```
public class Solution {
    public static long[] F = new long[50];
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static long count(int n, long k) {
        if (n == 0 || k == 0) return 0;
        else if (n == 1) return 1;
        else {
            if (k > F[n - 1]) return count(n - 1, F[n - 1]) + count(n - 2, k - F[n - 1]);
            else return count(n - 1, k);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F[0] = 1; F[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < 46; i++) F[i] = F[i - 2] + F[i - 1];
        int T = input.nextInt();
        while (T-- > 0) {
            int n = input.nextInt();
            long k = input.nextLong();
            System.out.println(count(n, k));
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to improve time complexity? Seems my solution has O(n^2) time complexity.

**Test case for this question:**

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 4 |  |
| 0 1 | 0 |
| 1 1 | 1 |
| 3 2 | 1 |
| 7 7 | 4 |

Comment: Did you try memoisation? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether `F[2]` is "BA" or "AB". Assuming that `F[2] = "BA"`, then one observation is that the first `k` letters don't change once the string length is at least `k`. Which means, for example, that when the input is 7 7, you really only need to compute F[5], since F[5] has more than 7 letters.

Comment: @user3386109 why would they need to clarify? F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2] is a complete ordered statement representing the concatenation of two strings.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ok, so then we agree that `F[2] = F[1] + F[0] = "B" + "A" = "BA"`. Right?

Comment: @user3386109 oh, oops, that reverses my answer, lol! Yes, we need clarification, lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, define `Fib(n)` to be the Fibonacci sequence where `Fib(0) = Fib(1) = 1`, and `Fib(n+2) = Fib(n+1) + Fib(n)`.

Note that `F[n]` has `Fib(n)` characters, with `Fib(n-1)` of them being `B`s.

Let `C(n, k)` be the number of `B`'s in the first `k` characters of `F[n]`.

The base cases are obvious

```
C(0, k) = 0
C(n, k) = 0 if k<=0
C(1, 1) = 1
C(2, k) = 1
```

In general:

```
C(n, k) = C(n-1, k)                         if k <= Fib(n-1)
        = Fib(n-2) + C(n-1, k - Fib(n-1))   otherwise
```

This is the observation that `F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2]` and `k` lies in either the first part or the second. The first part has `Fib(n-1)` characters of which `Fib(n-2)` of them are `B`'s.

If you precompute the Fibonacci numbers from `0` to `n`, then you can compute `C(n, k)` in O(`n`) arithmetic operations.

You tagged java, but here's a python solution including test cases:

```
def C(n, k):
    if n == 0: return 0
    total = 0
    fib = [1, 1]
    while len(fib) <= n and fib[-1] <= k:
        fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])
    n = min(n, len(fib) - 1)
    while True:
        if n <= 2:
            return total + 1
        elif k <= fib[n-1]:
            n -= 1
        else:
            total += fib[n-2]
            k -= fib[n-1]
            n -= 1

tcs = [
    ([0, 1], 0),
    ([1, 1], 1),
    ([3, 2], 1),
    ([7, 7], 4)
]

for (n, k), want in tcs:
    got = C(n, k)
    if got != want:
        print('C(%d, %d) = %d, want %d' % (n, k, got, want))
```

This includes an optimization which reduces `n` so that initially `k > Fib(n-1)`. This makes the code O(`min(n, log(k))`) arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a pattern related to Fibonacci numbers:

```
A
B
AB 1 + 1 (A count + B count)
BAB 1 + 2
ABBAB 2 + 3
BABABBAB 3 + 5
ABBABBABABBAB 5 + 8
      ^ k = 7
     BABABBAB 3 + 5
      ^ k = 2 (result = 3)
     BAB 1 + 2
      ^ k = 2 (result = 4)
     AB 1 + 1
     ^ k = 1 = A (result = 4)
```

Let `g(l, r, k)` represent the count of `B`s in the first `k` positions of `Fib[n] = l + r`. Then:

```
g(l, r, k):
  if (1, 1) == (l, r):
    return 1 if k == 2 else 0
  if (1, 2) == (l, r):
    return 1 if k < 3 else 2
  ll, rl = getFibSummands(l)
  lr, rr = getFibSummands(r)
  if k > l:
    return rl + g(lr, rr, k - l)
  return g(ll, rl, k)
```

This answer above may have misinterpreted the starting order of concatenation, which possibly should be `BA`, in which case, we would need to reverse `l, r`.

```
A
B
BA 1 + 1 (B count + A count)
BAB 2 + 1 
BABBA 3 + 2
BABBABAB 5 + 3
BABBABABBABBA 8 + 5
      ^ k = 7
BABBABAB
      ^ k = 7
     BAB
      ^ k = 2 (result = 3)
     BA
      ^ k = 2
      A
      ^ k = 1 (result = 4)
```

```
g(l, r, k):
  if (1, 1) == (l, r):
    return 1 if k == 2 else 0
  if (2, 1) == (l, r):
    return 1 if k < 3 else 2
  ll, rl = getFibSummands(l)
  lr, rr = getFibSummands(r)
  if k > l:
    return ll + g(lr, rr, k - l)
  return g(ll, rl, k)
```